# Что означает #define WINVER

Tags: winapi, c, c++

Без этого объявления моя программа не компилируется. Что это значит и почему 0x501?

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это объявление указывает версию винды, для которой производится сборка.

```
0x0500 - Windows 2000
0x0501 - Windows XP
0x0502 - Windows Server 2003
0x0600 - Windows Vista 
0x0601 - Windows 7
```

В Вашем случае версия ОС не определяется при компиляции. Поэтому `WINVER` объявляется вручную.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё понятно :)

Comment: Скажем так - это минимальная необходимая для работы программы версия операционной системы.

Comment: не всегда, мало как там условие написано. может быть для старых версий один код, для новых - другой.